# api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo returns partial fee 0

Tags: polkadot-js, api, runtime-api

With the update to the Polkadot-JS api depreciating rpc.payment.queryInfo in favor for api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo I am currently trying to migrate my code over. However I used to get the gas fee on the polkadot side by getting the partialFee attribute and now I am noticing even for a simple transfer this fee comes out to 0. I am attempting to call it with an unsigned transfer transaction

> {"signature":{"signer":{"id":"111111111111111111111111111111111HC1"},"signature":{"ed25519":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"era":{"immortalEra":"0x00"},"nonce":0,"tip":0},"method":{"callIndex":"0x0500","args":{"dest":{"id":"15JeACFd4oFAVxPdz9j9Uc5DGpm9oejH7hApQu548Yx2bNWR"},"value":100000000}}}

and my len parameter is the previous blockhash. I know the result should not be 0 so I am a little confused why I can get a real answer.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? Can you share more details where you are seeing the fee value is zero?